# .htaccess URL masking instead of redirecting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-masking

I'm trying to mask URL in away like while the real URL is **`www.somedomain.com/subfolder/index.php?p=page3`** it shows **`www.somedomain.com/subfolder/page3`** , I know such questions have been asked a lot on here and I did searched a lot but most of results didn't cater what I am looking for, also I almost know nothing but the basics about htaccess tweaking.

one result I got when i searched has the following htaccess code:

> Options +FollowSymLinks
>      Options +Indexes
>      RewriteEngine On
>      RewriteRule ^index.php$ %{QUERY_STRING} [C]
>      RewriteRule p=(.*) www.somedomain.com/subfolder/$1? [R=301,L]

It did the trick concerning the URL re-writing but it redirects the page instead of just masking the URL and it gives a 404 error, even when I removed the R=301 it didn't work.

Also the code above gives a 500 server error when I launch the index page of the subfolder **`www.somedomain.com/subfolder/`**.

Finally I'd like to mention that I'm testing with a sub-directory in localhost in case it make difference because some codes I've found on the web either just don't work at all or they give 500 server error.

Many Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I marked my answer for deletion - I confused myself by listing your destination first and your source second, as you had listed them in your question, so I had them reversed in the response (it's generally easier to write out what you're doing in the same order things appear in the rule - source, then destination). @faa's answer gets the order right. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# Prevent loops
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php         [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? [NC]
RewriteRule .*  %1/index.php?page=%2           [L]
```

Maps silently:

`http://www.somedomain.com/anyfolder/val` with or without trailing slash.

The above is the URL entered and shown in the browser's address bar.

To:

`http://www.somedomain.com/anyfolder/index.php?p=val`

Strings `anyfolder` and `val` are assumed to be dynamic.

For permanent redirection, replace `[L]` with `[R=301,L]`.

Comment: This answer is correct, just be aware (@JEES) that the second RewriteCond is specific to a two-level directory structure, as in the example in your question. If you need to apply it to a different number of directory levels you'll need to adjust it.

Comment: I think I'm confusing everybody, I apologize for that but what I'm trying to do is to convert my so called "ugly URL" which is produced by dynamic page insertion `www.somedomain.com/subfolder/index.php?p=page3` into a more appealing and SEO friendly "nice URL" like this one `www.somedomain.com/subfolder/page3` Or even into `www.somedomain.com/subfolder/pages/page3` while still loading the same page and injecting same query string.

Comment: `www.somedomain.com/subfolder/page3` that's what the rule in my answer does. Try it. Needless to say `www.somedomain.com/subfolder/page3` is the URL linked to or entered and shown in the browser's address bar. If it works for you, I can modify the answer for any number of levels in the directory structure, but, again, give it a try first.

Comment: @faa yes that worked it just needed some adjustment concerning the directory level everything is like charm now after I added another sub directory **([^/]+)** with (its corresponding **%3** .Thanks a lot @faa and @David for your help and time, just for the last part of the question I appended to the above code the following line to get rid of index.php `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index.php
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://www.somedomain.com  [R=301,L]` Many thanks again.

Comment: I got a problem similar to this, please see if you could help me. Here's the link http://stackoverflow.com/q/37046157/2549581